# The exception thrown from the property sheet pages' handlers

Tags: c++, exception, wtl, propertysheet

I'd like to catch and handle an excption by the top level application's try-catch block rather then inside the property sheet pages' handlers (for example, OnInitDialog handler). Thus, in the code below these exceptions are supposed to be handled in catch (...) block.

```
try {

CMyPropertySheet sheet;
sheet.DoModal();

} catch (...) {

// i want to handle an exception here

}
```

However when OnInitDialog throws an exception an assert appears (in debug mode) after running the windows destructors. Even if i call to EndDialog(m_hWnd, IDCANCEL) in the CMyPropertySheet destructor the assert remains. Could you please help to detect what is missing or wrang? I use WTL. My a property sheet claa is derived from CPropertySheetImpl.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't safely pass exception through C interfaces (like CreateDialog, DispatchMessage etc..). You must catch them all before they escape from the window procedure, transfer them somehow to the caller, and then rethrow them from there. You can do it generically in C++0x, but you probably don't have support for it yet. Try using `boost::exceptions` to approximate it in C++03.